# Check if two columns are one-to-one in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

How can I check if values in two columns in a table are one-to-one in SQL? I am thinking about grouping by the two columns and get the first value, in Python, it'd be like:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).first()
```

Sample data:

```
           col1   col2   timestamp                data  

      1    1      2      2017-01-02 13:14:53.040  10.0
      2    1      2      2017-01-02 13:14:54.040  10.0
      3    1      4      2017-01-02 13:14:55.040  10.0
      4    10     33     2017-01-02 13:14:56.040  10.0
                  ...
```

Expected output:

```
           col1   col2   timestamp                data  

      1    1      2      2017-01-02 13:14:53.040  10.0
      
      3           4      2017-01-02 13:14:55.040  10.0
      4    10     33     2017-01-02 13:14:56.040  10.0
                  ...
```

Is there an equivalent in SQL? If not, what's the best way to check if the two columns are one-to-one in SQL?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Are the columns in the same table?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff the columns are in the same table. Please see edited question for sample data and desired results.

Comment: why is col1=10, col2=33 in the result? (If there is only one row containing col1=10 then it must be 1:1 with col2, or is there something else you need but haven't explained?)

Comment: can you please always tell us which database you actually use (add as a tag to the question) "sql" isn't specific enough for us to know what syntax to use in our solutions

Comment: Hi @PaulMaxwell col1=10, col2=33 is in the results because I want to group by [col1, col2] to find the possible combinations of them and thus check the one-to-multiple relationship if there's any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the first row for a given pair of values, where "first" is based on the timestamp:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```